# AlamofireImage issues in Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, alamofire, alamofireimage

I'm trying to use AlamofireImage in a  project that I'm coding in Swift 4. The pod install went fine, but when I go to import the module I get the error "Could not build Objective-c module AlamofireImage"

I also noticed a bunch of compiler errors regarding AlamofireImage:

[image]

Is there an issue on my end, or does AlamofireImage simply not work in Swift 4? I'm trying to set up an image cache like so (Swift 3 code):

```
    Alamofire.request(urlString)
        .responseImage { response in

            if let downloadedImage = response.result.value {
                // image is here.
                imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                self.image = downloadedImage
            }
    }
```

Comment: you are using latest version of swift but alamofire pod is not updated as per the latest version that's why you are getting errors

Comment: run pod install to update the pods and remove any version constraint

Comment: after pod install command still its not fixed then go to pod settings select alamofire and in build settings select appropriate swift version.

Answer (score 0):

quit Xcode, go to the terminal, then goto your project directory and hit the following command:

```
pod install
```

make sure your pod file looks like this

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'SwiftNetworking' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
    pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator', '~> 2.2'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
end
```